# Check Gmail IMAP via PHP for new messages in a loop

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I am studying an application to trigger a PHP script based on new IMAP emails arriving on Gmail. What's the best way to know a new email has arrived on a Gmail IMAP account? I can't think of anything but to configure a cron job. I am running PHP + Nginx on a Linux (Ubuntu) box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that that's just the way celular companies developers are doing to verify their clients gmail.

Well, start making the connection normaly, then:

```
$t1=time();//mark time in
$tt=$t1+(60*1);//total time = t1 + n seconds

do{
    if(isset($t2)) unset($t2);//clean it at every loop cicle
    $t2=time();//mark time
    if(imap_num_msg($imap)!=0){//if there is any message (in the inbox)

        $mc=imap_check($imap);//messages check
        //var_dump($mc); die;//vardump it to see all the data it is possible to get with imap_check() and them customize it for yourself


    }else echo 'No new messagens';

    sleep(rand(7,13));//Give Google server a breack
    if(!@imap_ping($imap)){//if the connection is not up
        //start the imap connection the normal way like you did at first
    }

}while($tt>$t2);//if the total time was not achivied yet, get back to the beginning of the loop
```

And that's it.

By the way, here's some good informations about how IMAP works. My point is that: as IMAP makes possible to mantain virtually a kind of "Live Sync" connection, if you don't want to configure a MTA to receive email (like me), so IMAP is a real option for get "email pusshed" to you.

- The connection stays active from 5 to 10 minutes each time you connect to your email, unless you manually disconnect
- Gmail does limit each account to 10 simultaneous connections.
- An IMAP account, though, shoud check the mailbox and then keep an active channel to the IMAP server (IMAP-IDLE) for the preset industry standard of 29 minutes before it times out. If you set your Auto-Retrieve setting to between 20-30 minutes, that should keep your phone connected to the remote IMAP box.
- When GMAIL gets an email it should send a response to the IMAP idle session and mobiPush should pick it up almost instantly.
- All schedule to retrieve your Gmail mail every 10 minutes, this option will sync incoming E-mail immediately when it arrives at the Gmail servers.

Answer (score 2):

There's only two ways to get info from an email account, connect to it, reading it regularly (for example, by a cron-job) for new messages, or have the email forwarded to your own server, which pipes new email arriving into a PHP script.

[Zend_Mail](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html), part of the Zend Framework has Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap (which can be used without the rest of the MVC structure) which can connect to Gmail to poll an account.

Comment: Thank you, Alister. As I am using Google Apps in my domain, what solution would you recomend? If cronjob, would you have an example?